# JS automatically round long numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple array:

```
result = [{"egn":79090114464},{"egn":92122244001},{"egn":10005870397643185154},{"egn":10000330397652279629},{"egn":10000330397652279660},]
```

And when I append values from it to div element JS automatically round the numbers, so:

**10005870397643185154** becomes **10005870397643186000**

**10000330397652279629** becomes **10000330397652280000**

**10000330397652279660** becomes **10000330397652280000**

How to avoid that ?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9x5nqtc/)

Comment: Any integer larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` cannot be represented exactly with JavaScript numbers. This is true of all IEEE-math systems. You can try the relatively new `BigInt` type if its platform support is adequate for what you need.

Comment: @Pointy What about if cast to string or something like that ?

Comment: If they are strings in your data structure, that's fine. In your sample code, they are numeric constants.

Comment: [decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) can handle quite big numbers where JavaScript has to stop. This has a performance impact, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All numbers in JavaScript are stored as doubles (64 bit IEEE-754), which while allowing numbers as large as 1e308 (real max is higher, i don't exactly what it is) is only precise up to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which is 2<sup>53</sup> - 1 (`9007199254740991`) due to how doubles work.

If you a precise integer that's larger than this, use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). Note that it only performs a subset of number operations and can only be operated on by other BigInts.

You can use a BigInt literal by adding `n` to the end of the number.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
result = [{"egn":79090114464n},{"egn":92122244001n},{"egn":10005870397643185154n},{"egn":10000330397652279629n},{"egn":10000330397652279660n},]
            $("#foreigners_list").empty();
            $.each(result, function(key, data) {
                $("#foreigners_list").append("<a href='#' onClick='foreignerHrefClick("+data.egn+")' class='foreigner_egn_href'>" + data.egn + "</a><br />");
            })

})

function foreignerHrefClick(egn) {
    console.log(egn);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foreigners_list"></div>
```